# Formula for div id to match a getFullYear date

Tags: javascript, object, get

I have some code pending that won't work because I think I am comparing two different types of data in an if statement and for the life of me I can't figure out how to get them to compare to each other properly. I want to get the current year and compare it to the id of a div tag which is also labeled with a year. My sample code (using W3 fiddler for testing):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body onload="myFunction()">
    
    <h2>Test Code</h2>
    
    <p id="2021"></p>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var actualYear = new Date().getFullYear();
      var divName = document.getElementById(actualYear);
        
      if (divName = actualYear) {
        document.writeln(actualYear);
        document.writeln(divName);
        }
    }
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

This code correctly gets the full year of "2021" for actualYear, and it pulls the correct text from the div id of "2021" for divName, however when I change the if statement to include "==" to demand an exact match the formula breaks, even though I have exact matches from the snippet above. I have tried adding parseInt to the divName code but that doesn't work. I have added .innerHTML at the end which DOES work, but for my purposes I can't have any HTML in-between my div tags in this section so that is not an option. Any suggestions or clever workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `divName` does not hold the id attribute but the whole `HTMLElement`. So you need to change it to

```
  var actualYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  var divName = document.getElementById(actualYear).getAttribute("id");
    
  if (divName === actualYear) {
    document.writeln(actualYear);
    document.writeln(divName);
  }
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you SO much for this!